# Bottom:0 not working when position:absolute applied

Tags: html, css, position

I am unsure what I am doing wrong to get my div `#buttonLine` to display at the bottom of the `#pdfBannerRight` div.

I have applied `height: 100%;` to `pdfButtonWrap` and `bottom:0` to get the div to stretch the entirety of the container and then applied `bottom:0` to `#buttonLine`.

Does anyone see why `#buttonLine` is not displaying at the bottom of its container?

```css
#pdfBannerRight {
 width: 50%;
 background: #2f2f2f;
 height: 450px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 20%;
 right: 0;
}
#pdfBannerRightCont {
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
#pdfButtonWrap {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 height: 100%;
}
#buttonLine {
 width: 80px;
 height: 143px;
 border-top: 4px solid #FFF;
 border-right: 4px solid #FFF;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
}
.pdfSliderButton {
 text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
 margin: 8px 8px 8px 13px;
 color: #2f2f2f;
 background: #FFF;
 background: #b82222;
 font-size: 50px;
 vertical-align: middle;
 outline: none;
 border: none;
 cursor: pointer;
```

```html
<div id="pdfBannerRight">
     <div id="pdfBannerRightCont">
      <div id="pdfButtonWrap">
       <div id="buttonLine">
        <button type="button" class="previous pdfSliderButton" id="slickPrev" role="button" data-role="none">&#8249;</button>
        <button type="button" class="next pdfSliderButton" id="slickNext" role="button" data-role="none">&#8250;</button>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Because your example shows `position: relative;` not `position: absolute;`?

Comment: Gotcha. Didn't think `position: absolute` would work nested in another `position:absolute`. This fixed it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a mistake, just turn `position` to `absolute` and your `div` will go to the bottom.

```
#buttonLine {
  width: 80px;
  height: 143px;
  border-top: 4px solid #FFF;
  border-right: 4px solid #FFF;
  - position: relative;
  + position: absolute
  bottom: 0;
}
```